# itext7 renders incorrect vowel diacritic in Hindi language

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am using itext7 version 8 for PDF rendering in Java.

We need Hindi language font in table headers for the reports as shown in the image below.

[image]

In case of the header named "Rating" the correct Hindi font is `रेटिंग` but you see the diacritic is on the third letter instead of second.

The same issue is with the other headers too.

I found a [similar Hindi font issue in pyfpdf](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/issues/109) as well. Sharing it here for better understanding of the problem.

Let me know in any way I can help in resolving this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967567/itext7-pdfcalligraph-module-not-working-as-expected-for-indic-font?rq=2 (are you loading the module pdfCalligraph?)